# Property issue in Objective C, 'score' not found on object of type pointer

Tags: objective-c

I just started out programming in Objective C. This is very simple stuff but im wondering what im missing on my knowledge of properties, as far as I understand this should work but it gives me the error:

```
Property 'score' not found on object of type 'Player *'
```

I have a Player class and the code as follows below, each bolded is a separate file

**Player.h has:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Player : NSObject
@property int score;
@end
```

**Player.m has:**

```
#import "Player.h"
@implementation Player
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self){
    _score = 5000;
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

**main.m has**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Player.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    Player *firstPlayer = [[Player alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The default score is %i", [firstPlayer score]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you copied and pasted everything correctly?  This shouldn't even compile as posted.

Comment: I didn't but I edited it. I had to type it all in because I'm new to this site and copy/paste wasn't working well for me. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

**Player.h** is missing the following line which should go between the `#import` and `@property` lines:

```
@interface Player : NSObject
```

Where `NSObject` may be a different class, but needs to be whatever you intend to be subclassing.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to type everything in and I accidentally left that out. that line is included already. I'll edit it. Any other ideas?

(Is it potentially that it already inherts an init from the NSObject class, and so I can't write my own "init" unless i change the name to something like "initWithScore"?)